# Removing all my hardcoded URLs with get_site_url()

Tags: php, functions, urls, site-url

In my php files, I would like to remove all my hardcoded URLs (ex: http://mysite.com/) and replace them with the `get_site_url()` function.

My problem is with the php code of one of my functions (in functions.php) that adds a `_blank` attribute to all the links of my website except for the internal URLs.

```
function autoblank($text) {
    $return = str_replace('href=', 'target="_blank" href=', $text);
    $return = str_replace(
        'target="_blank" href="http://localhost.com/test/', 
        'href="http://localhost.com/test/', 
        $return
    );
    $return = str_replace('target="_blank" href="#', 'href="#', $return);
    return $return;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'autoblank');
add_filter('comment_text', 'autoblank');
```

How can I replace `http://localhost.com/test/` using `get_site_url()` so this code would work for any website? (not just `http://localhost.com/test/` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually already were pretty close:

```
function autoblank($text) {
    $return = str_replace('href=', 'target="_blank" href=', $text);
    $return = str_replace(
        'target="_blank" href="' . get_site_url(), 
        'href="' . get_site_url(), 
        $return
    );
    $return = str_replace('target="_blank" href="#', 'href="#', $return);
    return $return;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'autoblank');
add_filter('comment_text', 'autoblank');
```